# Reading 'old' messages from ActiveMQ virtual topic from C# (.net Core) with Apache.NMS

Tags: .net-core, activemq-classic, apache-nms

How do I read messages on a virtual topic with Apache.NMS?

After creating the connection and session and consumer, I do: "consumer.Receive();".

Messages sent while that code is running are received, but any messages that were already on the topic before that, are not.

I tried adding "?consumer.retroactive=true" to the topic but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've seen examples using durable subscribers, but when using a virtual topic I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that Virtual Topics (while powerful) are unique to ActiveMQ 5.x so any application built around their functionality will be difficult, if not impossible, to port to another broker if the need arises. If would recommend using, if possible, a standardized solution like shared topic subscriptions from JMS 2.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Problem was that I was reading from the wrong place: I was reading from a topic, while I should have been reading from a queue.

Virtual topics are topics, but you have to consume them from a consumer *queue*.

So, messages are pushed to "VirtualTopic.YourTopicName" and you should read from a QUEUE named "Consumer.YourConsumerName.VirtualTopic.YourTopicName". (Obviously this queue should exist before any messages are published.)

The reason that 'old' messages weren't read, is because they just weren't there.